# In MongoDB integer datatype is automatically type cast to doube?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

In MongoDB I have a collection with value (which I copied in `mongo` Shell) :

```
{
    "_id" : "5e74c0e32e13013cdea246e8",
    "year" : 1968
}
```

But when I fetch it in Java code, I am getting as :

```
{
    "_id" : "5e74c0e32e13013cdea246e8",
    "year" : 1968.0
}
```

Here is my code :

```
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(URI);
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .applicationName("mflix")
            .build();
    MongoClient connection = MongoClients.create(settings);
    MongoDatabase database = connection.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<Document> movieDetails = database.getCollection("student");
    try(MongoCursor<Document> its = movieDetails.find().limit(1).iterator())
    {
        while(its.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(its.next());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.close();
```

Can someone please explain why integer is getting converted to double while I am trying to fetch in java.

Comment: By default the number in a document is a `double` (see [Data types in mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberlong)). If you want your Java application to map it to an integer, you have do it explicitly by defining a `Movie` `POJO` class and declaring the `year` field as an `int`. Also, see [POJO suppor by MongoDB Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/bson/pojos/).

Comment: Also, see this [mapping of Bson data type to Java data type](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/bson/documents/).

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain why integer is getting converted to double
>   while I am trying to fetch in java.

A document in `movie` colection:

```
{ "name" : "Star Wars", "year" : 1977 }
```

Lets consider this Java code

```
MongoCollection<Document> movies = db.getCollection("movie");
Document d1 = movies.find(new Document()).iterator().tryNext();
System.out.println("> " + d1.get("name") + " : " + d1.get("year"));
```

Prints, `> Star Wars : 1977.0`

This is because of the data type of the `year` field when input from the `mongo` shell. By default, the number data is a floating-point *double* value.

If you know (ahead) that the database has a *double* value and you want it as an *integer* in your application, you can simply cast that specific field to an integer as follows:

```
System.out.println("> " + ((Double) d1.get("year")).intValue()); // prints > 1977
```

But, the shell also provides other data types for specific needs; see [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html). The following shows that an integer number can be stored in the database and retrieved from your Java application.

In the shell insert the following document:

```
{ name: "Return of Jedi", year: new NumberInt(1983) }
```

And, retrieve from the same Java code (without the cast to integer), which prints, `> Return of Jedi : 1983`

---

**Mapping Document to Java Class**

How to make your Java application see a specific field type as an integer (as in the example, the `year`field) and use the collection's document as a Java object? Suppose you have the movie collection and it can be represented a Java POJO in your application; the `Movie.java`:

```
public class Movie {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private int year;

    public Movie() {
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    // other get/set methods, etc.
}
```

Note the `year` field is declared an `int` in the above `Movie` class (and assume the database field stores as the default floating-point number).

The code that maps the database document and the Java POJO ([Plain Old Java Objects](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/bson/pojos/)) class is by using "codecs". The data is converted to a Java object that can be used in the application without any modifications.

A *codec* specifies how the document BSON data is converted. There are default and custom codecs. In the following code we use the default codecs to map the database to Java data (and it works  in this case). For complex requirements, you can build a custom codec.

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry =
    fromRegistries(
        MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));

MongoCollection<Movie> movies = db.getCollection("movie", Movie.class
                                  .withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
Movie m1 = movies.find(new Document()).iterator().tryNext();
System.out.println("> " + m1.getName() + " : " + m1.getYear()); // > Star Wars : 1977
```

To *insert* a document using the `Movie` POJO:

```
Movie document = new Movie();
document.setName("Empire Strikes Back");
document.setYear(1980);
movies.insertOne(document);
```

Comment: In my scenario, I don't know the datatype present in the MongoDB collection. While retrieving the data I want to know the datatype of each field. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: You can use this aggregation [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) operator to query the datatype of a field.

Comment: In `mongo` shell you can run the query: `db.movie.aggregate( [ { $addFields: { year_type: { $type: "$year" } } } ] )`

Comment: What is it you are trying to do (achieve) in Java code; I mean the purpose?

Comment: I want to fetch the data from MongoDB and store it in some other database. for creating the table in my new database. I need to know the datatype of the field

Comment: That is a different issue. I suggest you try to work with the available (and provided) info in this post and try to find a solution to your question about storing in another database. Also, you can post a new question with more details with that title (and you are likely to get direct answers).